# Replacing numbers in various formats with a word

Tags: python

I have a long sentence and I want to replace all numbers with a particular word. The numbers come in different formats, e.g.,

```
36
010616
010516 - 300417
01-04
2011 12
```

Is there function in Python for replacing these types of occurences with a word (say, "integer"), or how does the regex look for these?

Example:

```
"This is a 10 sentence with date 010616 and intervals 06-08 200-209 01 - 09 in years 2012 26"
```

should become

```
"This is a NUMBER sentence with date NUMBER and intervals NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER in years NUMBER NUMBER"
```

Comment: Use regex for replacing numbers with a particular word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Regex.

```
import re
s = "This is a 10 sentence with date 010616 and intervals 06-08 200-209 01 - 09 in years 2012 26"
print( re.sub("\d+", "NUMBER", s) )
```

**Output:**

```
This is a NUMBER sentence with date NUMBER and intervals NUMBER-NUMBER NUMBER-NUMBER NUMBER - NUMBER in years NUMBER NUMBER
```

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. Is it possible to have `NUMBER - NUMBER` and `NUMBER-NUMBER` occur as a single string `NUMBER`? In fact, any two occurences of `NUMBER` separated by a dash should appear as one `NUMBER`

Comment: Then this should help `print( re.sub("(\d+\s*-\s*\d+|\d+)", "NUMBER", s) )`

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. Is it possible to generalize it such that it also removes negative numbers, e.g. `-3200`, and not just positive as I showed in the example above?

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub('((?<=^)|(?<= ))[0-9- ]+(?=$| )', 'NUMBER', s)
'This is a NUMBER sentence with date NUMBER and intervals NUMBER in years NUMBER'
```

what it does is:

looking for numbers with minus signs and spaces `[0-9- ]+`

with space or beginning of string before match `((?<=^)|(?<= ))`

and space or end of string after match `(?=$| )`